# Regular expression for boolean expressions with ()&|~ as operators and groupers identifiers in various positions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've not been able to find any examples that cover my specific problem. I'm using the .NET c# regex library.  I have to parse a legacy file structure that uses long boolean expressions with their own format. I now have a need to replace specific identifier numbers with other text, and I can't my matching to work.

For example i need to match the number 1 in the following types of cases.
"1" |
"1 & 2" |
"2 | 1" |
"3 & (1 | 2)" |
"(3 | 1) & 2"

But not match in:
"11" |
"2 & 11" |
"11 | 3"

Further I'd prefer to match it to just the exact number, not any additional spaces or params. I'm hoping it can be done in one expression. I'm to the point I can only do it with multiple expressions and regex replacements. Any guru know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex, using lookahead and lookbehind, should do it for your examples.

```
//regex expression (the important part)
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)1(?!\d)");

//test input
var input1 = "\"1\" \"1 & 2\" \"2 | 1\" \"3 & (1 | 2)\" \"3( | 1) & 2\"";
var input2 = "\"11\" \"2 & 11\" \"11 | 3\"";

//replace and print result
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input1, "NEW"));
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input2, "NEW"));

// Output:
// "NEW" "NEW & 2" "2 | NEW" "3 & (NEW | 2)" "3( | NEW) & 2"
// "11" "2 & 11" "11 | 3"
```

This essentially means "capture all 1s, that aren't directly preceded or followed by a digit".

For more info on the lookahead/lookbehind assertions, check out this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

To match just "1" by itself, not as part of another value, you can probably use this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b1\b");
```

The "\b" before and after match on a word boundary (the transition from a word to a non-word character or vice-versa). Based on your examples, the above will work.